# How to make show desktop work only on the current workspace?

Tags: unity

I am an active user of workspaces in Ubuntu. Until recently, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (`show desktop`) acted only on the current workspace.

For example, one might want to minimize the applications in the current workspace, open a file, and then bring some of them back. The current implementation works on all workspaces uniformly which is counter-intuitive to me. The reason for the existence of workspaces is the separation of logic -- one can have a browser open in one workspace, a text editor in another, a terminal in a third.

The current functionality goes against this idea. Is there a way to restrict the action of the show desktop command to a single workspace only?

Comment: (By default Ctrl+Super+D shows desktop; not Ctrl+Alt+D - at least in 12.04.)

Comment: I think my default key is different since I had upgraded from a previous version of Ubuntu. The functionality remains the same though.

Comment: Interesting, what window manager are you running? For me on 12.04 with Gnome 3 Fallback, Ctrl+Alt+D has exactly the functionality you want already (only minimize windows on the current workspace). So, this seems to be something in the window manager. Edit: Just saw question is tagged with `unity`, must be a setting or change there.

Comment: You may post it in launchpad. That would be a nice option for Unity. It may be a bug in Unity

Answer (score 4):

There is a [bug report about this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/975640) for 12.04. The bug's status is **Fix Committed**, meaning the fix will only be available in the next release.

In the meantime I can only recommend **gnome3**. There <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> works as expected.
In case you want to give it a try:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

Restart, and at the login, choose GNOME (first in the list):

[image]

Where to find the **show desktop keybinding**:
open `dconf-editor` and navigate to schema `org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings`.
You should find a key named show-desktop with its current value.

Comment: I have 12.04 and it doesn't seem to work as you describe, instead I have all windows in all workspaces minimized. This makes sense because the name of the action set in `Keyboard Shortcuts` is `Hide All Normal Windows`, not `Show Desktop`. Where did you find the `Show Desktop` action?

Comment: Is this using gnome-shell? Navigate to the keybindings in dconf-editor to check the setting.

Comment: No, unity3d, regular ubuntu installation